# WP7 InvokeScript error

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-7

I have some difficulties with the method `InvokeScript` on wp7:

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementsByName('email').value='{0}'", _email));
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementsByName('pass').value='{0}'", _pass));
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.forms[0].submit();");
```

Unfortunately, when I try to submit information, using `(document.forms[0].submit())`, an exception is thrown with the message:

> An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020101.

What may the problem be?

Comment: Not sure, but may be a security related issue, not allowing a script to direct submit a form!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure that IsScriptingEnabled is to true, but I assume you did it.

Your problem is probably that you call the code too soon. It seems that the DOM is not ready for manipulation when the Navigated event occurs. Example:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Wb.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(Wb_Navigated);
        MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown);

        Wb.NavigateToString("<html><body><form action='http://google.com/'></form></body></html>");
    }

    void Wb_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Wb.InvokeScript("eval", "document.forms[0].submit();"); // Throws 80020101
    }

    private void MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Wb.InvokeScript("eval", "document.forms[0].submit();"); // Works
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to actually see a solution to this problem though. Still very helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Script can directly submit forms - I have an app that depends on that behavior. :)

The problem is that when there's no script on the page (and in some cases, when there's only a little script - I have not been able to isolate this), the browser does not load (or maybe loads and unloads) the script engine. When that happens, you simply cannot execute any script.

One thing that worked for me on a specific case was to make a local copy of the HTML, add random script to it, and load it as string in the browser, but that obviously will not work for everything.

Another alternative (though much more work) for me in another case was to use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to read the HTML and do the post myself.

Comment: thx for your answer - I already understood that the required script no found. But its surprised me, I think problem in syntax of call method, but I not so good in js.
I try your way about HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Your script calls seem to be fine.  Also, take a look at the other answer on this - it seems like @Kylerr actually found a timing issue. May solve your problem.