# WP8.1 InvokeScript Error

Tags: c#, invokescript

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 App. I have a problem with the InvokeScript method of the WebBrowser class.
I have this in my XAML:

And when I run this code:

```
myWebBrowser.Loaded += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
{
    webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "alert('foo')");
};
```

I get a System.SystemException on the line with InvokeScript that tells me this:

> An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020006.

When I run the same code for Windows Phone 8 (not 8.1) I don't get the exception.

Any ideas why I get an error with WP 8.1?

Comment: It is DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME, "Unknown name".  Note in the MSDN Library article: "InvokeScript may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use InvokeScriptAsync."  Second argument must be string[], not string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911985/wp7-invokescript-error?rq=1).

The Loaded event is called too early. I used the LoadCompleted event instead. As long as I navigate to something (I've been putting *webBrowser.NavigateToString("");* ) the LoadCompleted event will be called only when the WebBrowser control has fully loaded content.

Here is the new code :

```
webBrowser.LoadCompleted += (object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) =>
{
    webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "alert('foo');");
};
```