# Windows Phone 8 Invoke script error?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am invoking javascript from code behind in windows mobile application.
I am using Windows Phone SDK 8.0 and Visual Studio 2012 for development.

I am getting following isuue when invoking

```
wbInnerContent.InvokeScript('scriptName', new String[] { jsonval });
```

> {System.SystemException: An unknown error has occurred. Error:
>   80020101.    at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NativeMethods.ValidateHResult(Int32 hr)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop.InvokeScript(String
>   scriptName, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.InvokeScript(String scriptName,
>   String[] args)    at
>   OneVoiceAfrica.Header.d__16.MoveNext()}

I am new to mobile application development.
kindly help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `IsScriptingEnabled` is true and maybe the issue could be due to  `Loaded event` is called too early.

```
  webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
```

[WP7 InvokeScript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911985/)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611226/wp8-1-invokescript-error)